# spatie/laravel-medialibrary, filters on getMedia() function not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I am trying to get media for certain modal as follows:

```
public function show(Gallery  $gallery)
    {
       $images = $gallery->getMedia('default'); //returns images
       // $images = $gallery->getMedia('default', ['name', 'original_url']); //returns empty 
       return response()->json(['data' => $images]);
    }
```

when not adding filters I get the correct data as follows:

```
{
    "data": {
        "686cc1b1-cfdc-425d-9b93-c99290f0d35e": {
            "name": "Screenshot from 2022-06-27 23-29-29",
            "file_name": "Screenshot-from-2022-06-27-23-29-29.png",
            "uuid": "686cc1b1-cfdc-425d-9b93-c99290f0d35e",
            "preview_url": "",
            "original_url": "http://app.test/storage/media/25/Screenshot-from-2022-06-27-23-29-29.png",
            "order": 1,
            "custom_properties": [],
            "extension": "png",
            "size": 10546
        }
    }
}
```

but when I use filters I get empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to retrieve single media, then you can chain property name

```
$gallery->getMedia('default')[0]->name;
```

or

```
$gallery->getFirstMedia('default')->name;
```

If you want to return json with name and original_url field for every media, that can be achieved by using API resource, something like this:

```
$images = $gallery->getMedia('default');

return MediaResource::collection($images);
```

and in MediaResource class you have:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'original_url' => $this->original_url
    ];
}
```

Comment: This is one approach. I was just trying to use the filters parameter that getMedia() method has as second parameter. There should be a purpose for it right?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't find an example for this in docs. You can take a look at this github issues https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/5 https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/613 https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1228 . Maybe it can help you.